# Netty Client Won't send more data after a while

Tags: java, netty

I'm writing an application that consists of a Server and a Client written with Java using Netty.

I've not found a real answer to this question, but I wonder why my Server-Client connection stops being able to sen data after a while if not used. The "keepAlive" option is set to True, and it all works fine until that point where enough time has passed for the client to "disconnect" however the server doesn't receive a disconnect status.
Just generally curious, does keepAlive ping-pong the client/server or do I have to do that myself?

Thanks!

Comment: You should provide more information like netty version and if possible the code you use to setup your client and server (Bootstrap & Pipeline).

Comment: It's pretty much the normal setup with a client-server bootstrap with a pipeline, with the options "keepAlive" and "tcpNoDelay". The application works just fine while you actually send messages between them but when you don't use the client for a while it just won't "flush" the messages to the server anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things that worth take a look at is if there is some networking gear, such as firewalls, that might had closed your connection, bear in mind that is not in the protocol the connection state handling. So it is likely that you have a [half closed connection](https://superuser.com/questions/298919/what-is-tcp-half-open-connection-and-tcp-half-closed-connection).

If you did set the `keepAlive` option make sure it is performing those `ping` over the wire. Best thing to do is to check in both sides of the connection if the socket still open.

While the connection is alive but idle (the client is not receiving data) check if the connection is in status `ESTABLISHED`. And do the same in the server side. From there with tools such as `Wireshark` and `trace` try to establish if the connection was dropped on the server or it was killed by a firewall.

Comment: Tested it a bit, seems like it doesn't disconnect, the streams just stops working after a while... Do you got any suggestions on how to test this further?